# Specs2 running a matcher outside of the test class in an anonymous inner class

Tags: scala, specs2

I am running the following test:

```
class FooTest extends SpecWithJUnit with MockServer {

"Foo" should {
 "fail" in new ctx {

    givenAListenerThatAlwaysFailsWhenExcecuted()
    foo.runMethodThatInvokesAListener
  }
 }
} 

trait MockServer extends BeforeAfterAll with MustMatchers {

  private val wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(9000))

  def givenAListenerThatAlwaysFailsWhenExcecuted() = {
    val listener = new RequestListener {
    override def requestReceived(request: Request, response: Response): Unit = {
    true must beFalse
  }
}
  wireMockServer.addMockServiceRequestListener(listener)
  listener
}

 override def beforeAll(): Unit = wireMockServer.start()
 override def afterAll(): Unit = wireMockServer.stop()
}
```

When I run it, I see the exception in the console but the test itself is not failing. How do I get it to fail?

Comment: Probably the listener is executed in another thread or the exception never arrives to the code inside the test. As the test is expressed, looks like you would like 'runMethodThatInvokesAListener' to fail when the listener fails. But that is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `MustThrownMatchers` instead of `MustMatchers` so that any failed expectation such as `true must beFalse` get thrown out of `new ctx { ... }`.

Otherwise `true must beFalse` is just a simple `MatchResult[Boolean]` value which is happily created inside the body of the anonymous `ctx` class.